# How do I set up a battery pack to be treated like a laptop battery on a desktop motherboard?

Tags: 22.04, power-management, battery, acpi

As I understand it there is a serial interface in a laptop battery which communicates the battery state at intervals to the laptop's OS. I am setting up a desktop system with what amounts to a laptop-like power system, with a 3s lithium battery pack that will power the PC via a dc-dc boost and a 12V-input mini ATX power module. I would like for the PC to think that it is a laptop, and have all the laptop-like power functions like auto-sleep and power-down, battery charging indicator, time left etc.. I can program a microcontroller to monitor the battery and supply all the relevant stats to some kind of serial interface on the motherboard (usb? an unused ps/2? maybe use the TPM SPI interface that I won't be needing? would that be possible? I'd prefer not to use USB).

What I would like to know is **what protocol I need to implement and how do I get the system to recognise the port** I'm connecting the battery to? Targeting ubuntu-unity 22.04.

Comment: IIRC connecting either the USB cable or serial cable between the PC and the UPS will automatically be recognised

Comment: thanks @24601, but this is not a commercial UPS I'm connecting, it's an entirely homebrew battery pack, and self coded (arduino) BMS. I'm hoping for some clues where to look for the information of which protocols the commercial UPS implemented to get the automatic detection behaviour.